# ¿Por qué SQL Server Management Studio se cierra automáticamente cuando intento abrir un diagrama de base de datos?

Tags: sql-server

Buen día saludos a todos, agradecería en gran manera que me pudiesen ayudar con el siguiente problema:

### SSMS se cierra automáticamente al abrir un diagrama de base de datos

Tengo un base de datos ya creada con tablas y su respectivo diagrama.
El error surge cuando intento abrir nuevamente ese diagrama de base de datos, el ***SSMS*** se cierra automaticamente sin mostrar mensaje alguno de error.
De antemano agradecería su valiosa ayuda.

### Datos adicionales

1. Sistema Operativo ***W10 PRO-1809.***
2. ***SQL Server 2016 SP2.***
3. SSMS 18.4 en español.
4. Modo de autenticación ***Windows.***
5. Software ejecutado como administrador.
6. Propietario de base de datos: [sa].

Comment: Has revisado el consumo de memoria? Recuerda que sigue siendo una aplicación de 32 bits

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo, aunque se me ocurre que el fallo pudiera ser porque la versión 18.5 ssms la obtuve por actualización, quizás instalando de cero, no pasaría, no lo desinstalo porque tengo varias bases de datos y no se como exportarlas para luego restaurarlas, pero si a alguien le pasa igual y lo soluciona comentelo.

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema desde hace ya bastante tiempo, y parece ser que solución no le han dado. Muy profesional por parte de MS.
Y no son los único problemas que estoy teniendo con MS. Con VS 2019 es una odisea.
Yo ahí lo dejo.
Donde podria bajar el ssms con la version 17.??
gracias y un saludo a todos.

Answer (score 2):

SSMS 18.X, ha tenido problemas con los diagramas, desde su desaparición en la 18.0 ha su vuelta en la 18.1.
De momento la versión más estable con el tema de los diagramas es la 17.9. Dado que SSMS es un cliente, puedes tener instalados ambos y utilizar la 17.9 cuando quieras trabajar con diagramas. Por otra parte si se cierra, seguro que deja un rastro en el visor de eventos, y en algún archivo de log. Te recomendaría que lo mirases, expusiese el error explicito que te ofrece, por si existe algo que se pueda hacer.

[Abrir el visor de eventos](https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/3392-como-abrir-usar-visor-eventos-windows-10/)

[Log Sql Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Gracias por responder a mi pregunta, voy a tratar de aplicar esta solución, gracias y Dios te bendiga.

Comment: De nada. Esa solución seguro que te funciona ;)